# Как связать несколько команд в одну (для cmd)?

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd, консоль

Подскажите как выполнить несколько команд сразу введя в командной строке cmd:

> C:\app.exe /h /s /e

Задача запретить появление окна формы на всех командах и связать команды вместе.

Код из Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var form = new Form1();
        if (args.Contains("/h"))
        {
            form.Check1();
        }
        if (args.Contains("/s"))
        {
            form.Check2();
        }
        if (args.Contains("/e"))
        {
            form.Check3();
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Отдельные потоки заведите под каждую задачу...

Comment: Каким образом? Я не особо разбираюсь в C# подскажите как выглядят потоки в коде.

Comment: Это называется "напишите за меня". Если вы плохо в чем-то разбираетесь - разберитесь лучше и попробуйте как вам подсказывают.

Comment: Могли не отвечать в теме загадками ради своего превосходства.

Comment: Раз вы плохо разбираетесь - вам вообще лучше не отвечать, получается...

Comment: Те кто отвечает не страдают предвзятостью как Вы. Они повышают свои навыки помогая новичкам, совершенствуя свои знания.